# [Docker][PHP] NumberFormatter::formatCurrency incompatible between 7.4.29 and 7.4.28

Tags: php, internationalization, docker-registry, icu

(Same as https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1301 )

The results of running the following script were different between `php:7.4.29-fpm-alpine` and `php:7.4.28-fpm-alpine`.

```php
<?php

$fmt = new \NumberFormatter('JA_JP', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatString = $fmt->formatCurrency(0, 'JPY');

var_dump($formatString);
```

### Result

- php:7.4.28-fpm-alpine (I expects)

  ```bash
  string(4) "￥0"
  ```
- php:7.4.29-fpm-alpine

  ```bash
  string(3) "¥0"
  ```

## (My) problem

Is there any way to get the results in `php:7.4.29-fpm-alpine` to be what they were in `php:7.4.28-fpm-alpine` ? (Is there a workaround?)

## Way to reproduce

see https://github.com/sogaoh/reproduce-incompatibility-of-format-currency (README.md)

### Remarks

( unconfirmed ) I'm guessing that there is a similar problem between

- 8.0.19 and 8.0.18
- 8.1.6 and 8.1.5

Comment: Can you explain in words what the difference in output is? I can see the one is 4 bytes and the other is 3, but there doesn't seem to actually be a space there, just a different version of the Yen symbol? Also, this doesn't seem to be a change in PHP itself, but some other OS component - perhaps as mentioned on the Github issue something in the ICU library: https://3v4l.org/82uqr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Install [package: icu-data-full](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=icu-data-full) additionally.

refs

- https://github.com/sogaoh/reproduce-incompatibility-of-format-currency/pull/2/files
- https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1301#issuecomment-1139142261

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that the .28 version uses `\uffe5` 'Fullwidth Yen Sign, and the .29 version uses `\u00a5` 'Yen Sign.

As noted in the github issue comment, it's likely a change in the underlying ICU library between builds of the image, as opposed to an issue in the image, Alpine, or PHP themselves. As an interim fix you could use a modified image that installs a pinned version of ICU, but YMMV.

Alternatively you could shim in a simple replacement like:

```php
str_replace("\xc2\xa5", "\xef\xbf\xa5", $formatter_output);
```

Though the issue itself is fairly cosmetic, and IMO the original use of a fullwidth glyph for the currency symbol was the more questionable option.